# Inline date or picker with Swift in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Does anyone have any sample code for implementing an inline date picker or picker view in a table view with Swift in Xcode 6?

For example, similar to the Calendar app, when you create a new event and click the start time then the date picker drops down.

I found examples of this in iOS 7 with objective-c but am having trouble getting something similar to work in Swift.

Comment: https://github.com/DylanVann/DVDatePickerTableViewCell